# Android service that only allows WiFi Internet connectivity for installed apps?

Tags: android

is there a way I can force Internet access for installed apps
to only go through wifi, ie prevent any data transfer via the radio/3G
interface?
I'm looking for a solution that wouldn't require a jailbroken phone,
so I guess fooling around with iptables might be out of the question.
Please let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could use the solution for this question:

[Android: Stop/Start service depending on WiFi state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7094606/android-stop-start-service-depending-on-wifi-state)

You'll need to modify it a bit, but that'll let you know when WiFi is activated and deactivated. I'm not sure what the purpose of your application is, but I certainly wouldn't recommend doing it.

Comment: Hmm, it is similr to what I'm trying to do; but I'd like more fine-grained control, ie, for some apps, when my service is on, they connect exclusively through a preferred wifi AP, and then everything else goes through 3G

Comment: There's simple no way to do that. You can't control how other applications connect.